# Django facebook login

Tags: django, facebook-oauth, python-social-auth

I had facebook login setup using `python-social-auth` a while ago, but it stopped working. Now I updated social auth library and set it up again.
I went trough a few errors from incorrect secret, incorrect facebook setup up till "Authentication process canceled". Now it seems like whole process went successfully, however once I am redirected back, I am still not logged in.

I think, I have same problem with google auth, which worked alright even before I updated library, so I guess some configuration changed.
I upgraded from `python-social-auth==0.2.21` to `python-social-auth==0.3.6`.

I checked newest documentation and changed a few bits, that were different with no help.
I got standard pipeline, social `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` first, updated context processors (prefix `social.apps.django_app` -> `social_django`), but still no help.

I already went trough quite a few files of the library and related ones to fix those errors.
Now I kinda don't know where should I look for problem and dig a bit.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it took me a lot of digging. I knew whole pipeline was going trough and there was user instance in the end + `request.user.is_authenticated()` returned true. However after redirect, I wasn't logged in.

In the end, I found out, I had to change `social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2` to `social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2` in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` (and same for GoogleOAuth2).
Very annoying and hard to find.